# Get the current emitted volume in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a little Python music player, and I thought that adding an audio visualizer would be a good idea.
So I started making it, but I need to get the current volume emitted by the music currently playing. I tried this `pygame.mixer.music.get_volume()` but it gives me the volume of the mixer, and not the volume emitted.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that, but not by much. Have a look here: https://github.com/Joeyyi/python-audio-visualizer/blob/master/Visualizer.py

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pygame.mixer.Sound.get_volume`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_volume()) to get the volume of a [`pygame.mixer.Sound`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) object:

```py
my_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound_file.wav")
```

```py
volume = my_sound.get_volume()
```

If you want to get the volume of a [`pygame.mixer.Channel`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel) you have to use [`pygame.mixer.Channel.get_volume()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel.get_volume).

```py
channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
```

```py
volume = channel.get_volume()
```